# I'm trying to animate a text but this code is not working

Tags: css, wordpress

```css
body {
  background-color: black;
}

.selector {
  font-size: 72px;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: transparent;
  -webkit-text-stroke: 1px #fff;
  background-image: linear-gradient(#fff, #fff);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  -webkit-background-clip: text;
  background-position: 0 -200px;
  animation: backcolor 5s linear infinte alternate;
}

@keyframes backcolor {
  100% {
    background-position: 0 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
</head>

<body>
  <h1 class="selector">Stack Overflow</h1>
</body>

</html>
```

I'm trying this animated text animation. Code isn't working from this line (animation: backcolor 5s linear infinte alternate;)

Comment: Please post a [mcve]

Comment: i think it's already minimal

Comment: Where is you html? have you read the article? It is minimal but no reproducible

Comment: I am doing it in WordPress.

Comment: It's not relevant, i'll suggest to post a working example (read the link i posted on previous comment) so we can see what is not working with your code. I know you are a new user of this site so i'll suggest you to read also [ask] to improve and learn how this community works.

Comment: Kindly check i have tried to do it...